# React Native FlatList Data is not Showing Data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

**I am Using Redux and My Problem is When First Time My Screen Loads I am getting error
undefined is not an object(evaluating 'response.data')**

**My Code Is**

```
function LaunchScreen(props) {
const [response, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
props.getProperties;
setData(props.properties);
}, []);
console.warn('///////////////DATA////////////////', response);
return (
<View style={styles.mainContainer}>
  <FlatList
    data={response.data}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={item.id}
        style={styles.propertyItem}
        onPress={() => this.navigateToDetail(item)}>
        <Image style={styles.banner} source={{uri: item.banner}} />
        <View style={{padding: 10}}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.shortDescription}>
            {item.shortDescription}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
  />
  <View style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
    <Button style={{width: '90%'}} title={'Give Donation'} />
  </View>
</View>
```

);
}

**And When I Refresh Screen Than I Got Response and Screen Data Loads**

Answer (score 2):

```
<View style={styles.mainContainer}>
{!(response.data === null || response.data === undefined)? 
  (<FlatList
    data={response.data}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={item.id}
        style={styles.propertyItem}
        onPress={() => this.navigateToDetail(item)}>
        <Image style={styles.banner} source={{uri: item.banner}} />
        <View style={{padding: 10}}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.shortDescription}>
            {item.shortDescription}
          </Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />):(<View><Text>Data Loading...</Text></View>)
}
</View>
```

Comment: try this way ! ping me if not work.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are setting data into a state, which takes a little bit of time, to fix this you can make following changes

```
   function LaunchScreen(props) {
    const [response, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
    props.getProperties;
    setData(props.properties);
    }, []);
    console.warn('///////////////DATA////////////////', response);
    return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
    {if(response && response?.data){
    <FlatList
        data={response.data}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={item.id}
            style={styles.propertyItem}
            onPress={() => this.navigateToDetail(item)}>
            <Image style={styles.banner} source={{uri: item.banner}} />
            <View style={{padding: 10}}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.shortDescription}>
                {item.shortDescription}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    }
    else{
    <Text>Data Loading...</Text>
    }}
      <View style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
        <Button style={{width: '90%'}} title={'Give Donation'} />
      </View>
    </View>
```

Comment: When I'm Using if else in code I'm getting  Expression expected error

Comment: I think add `return` before <Flatlist> and wrap whole flatlist component with round braces  and same inside else statement before <Text>

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<FlatList
  data={response.data}
  renderItem={({item}) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={item.id}
        style={styles.propertyItem}
        onPress={() => this.navigateToDetail(item)}>
        <Image style={styles.banner} source={{uri: item.banner}} />
        <View style={{padding: 10}}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.shortDescription}>
            {item.shortDescription}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because you haven't add return in the FlatList(renderItem prop)
Once you add it, it'll work.

```
<FlatList
    data={response.data}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
return(
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={item.id}
        style={styles.propertyItem}
        onPress={() => this.navigateToDetail(item)}>
        <Image style={styles.banner} source={{uri: item.banner}} />
        <View style={{padding: 10}}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.shortDescription}>
            {item.shortDescription}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )}}
  />
```